# After 16.10 upgrade, ethernet is not working

Tags: upgrade, internet, 16.10, ethernet

Ok. I really need help. I messed up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS so I decided that upgrading to 16.10 will fix the broken packages. It did, but now I can't use the internet. At all. I have a Lenovo Ideapad with Realtek ethernet adapter. It says that the ethernet is "not managed". I tried modifying the `managed=false` to `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` but that didn't work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

For me the following commands solved the issue and LAN connection was immediately detected.

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo service network-manager restart
```

if the above doesn't work try the following

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
sudo sed -i 's/false/true/g' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo reboot -i NOW
```

Good luck!

Comment: excellent! the "touch" command plus reboot did the trick for me...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Unfortunately, I needed to reinstall Ubuntu 16.10. And now I need to reinstall all the programs. Because Ubuntu live-USB doesn't have "Repair Current Install", which I consider a shame, since may other distros have that.